# How to change the local language using VB.Net in excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm trying to change the local language using VB.Net below is the sample code code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Sub Trial()
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("en-US")
End Sub
```

I don't have any experience on VB.Net so please let me know what is going wrong

Thanks

Comment: Also, IMO, you should not be changing a user's language.

Comment: @Rory There is some mismatch when reading the data from another language so need to do it.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your code, which should *never* be corrected by changing a user's settings!

Comment: @Rory I don't think so because reading a same value gives different output. For eg

 `Value : 5214.462`

  ` Value in Excel (English) : 5,214.46`

  ` Value in Excel (Dutch) : 5.214.462,00`

Comment: You don't need to change the system language. Just specify the culture when you read the data.

Comment: Still sounds like a code problem to me. A value in a cell doesn't change because you change language, so I can only assume you are doing something to interpret it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Can you elaborate more on how can one achieve that?

Comment: Maybe, if you were to actually show us how you are reading the data. You know, providing all the relevant information.

Comment: @Rory, it must be being read as a `String`, either because it's already text or because the number is being unadvisedly converted to a `String` first and then back to a number. The latter actually seems less likely because I would think that the initial conversion would output the correct group and decimal separators for the current culture, meaning that the second conversion would work. If the original data is text containing a dot though, that dot will be interpreted as a decimal separator in some cultures and a group separator in others.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Just to inform you people that this issue was resolved by unchecking a checkbox present in` File > options > Advanced > Use system separators`. If you uncheck this checkbox then Excel reads data as per the decimal, thousands separator mentioned by you else from the system language. This was the root cause for my issue. Thanks for your efforts. @Rory